# Сложение значений datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно вывести список сотрудников, которые отработали суммарно менее  8 часов в офисе от первого входа до последнего выхода. Я правильно понимаю что это возможно только через цикл?

1. 3 1 2018-04-28 09:00:00 2018-04-28 13:00:00
2. 4 1 2018-04-28 14:00:00 2018-04-28 18:00:00
3. 5 2 2018-04-28 10:03:00 2018-04-28 13:00:00
4. 6 2 2018-04-28 15:00:00 2018-04-28 18:00:00
5. 7 3 2018-04-29 09:00:00 2018-04-29 18:00:00
6. 8 1 2018-04-27 09:00:00 2018-04-27 18:00:00
7. 9 3 2018-04-27 09:00:00 2018-04-27 13:00:00
8. 10 3 2018-04-27 14:00:00 2018-04-27 18:00:00

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы найти даты и id сотрудников, которые отработали от первого входа до последнего выхода меньше 8 часов в этот день, удобно group by и having использовать:

```
select DATE(entrance), id_employee
from t1
group by DATE(entrance), id_employee
having timestampdiff(second, min(entrance), max(exit1)) < 28800
order by DATE(entrance), id_employee
```

[Результат](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f136f/2/0):

```
DATE(entrance) id_employee
2018-04-28  2
```

Answer (score 0):

modify вычитает одну дату из другой.

```
$now = DateTime("now");
$now->modify("-8 hour");
```

Общий синтаксис:

```
SELECT column-names
FROM table-name
WHERE column-name BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Comment: Смысл в том что за 1 день может быть сколь угодно входов выходов и нужно проверить все дни. Это же только все через цикл прогонять?

Comment: Какое отношение имеет это решение к sql?

Comment: @0xdb прямое отношение

Comment: @dimababin добавил `sql`-запрос который выведет только сотрудников удовлетворяющих условию

Comment: @DigitalCore Поясните пожалуйста, какое?